# Does Sony Cross-Buy apply for physical copies of games?

Tags: ps3, ps-vita

I just read about Sony's newly announced crossbuy feature. What I could not retrieve from the articles is if this feature is only for online bought games or also for games that have been bought in a real game store? Had Sony disclosed any info about this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it will be for games bought in stores as well. See [here](http://blog.eu.playstation.com/2012/08/14/sony-at-gamescom-2012-all-the-announcements/#comment-251855):

> If you purchase either a physical or digital version of an applicable PS3 title, you can download the Vita version at no extra cost.

Please note, however, you get a PSVita copy of a game when you buy the PS3 version, but not the other way around.

Comment: is that only if you hook it up to your PSN?  So second hand sellers/buyers of the game won't have that option?

Comment: Probably. As it's a digital version of the game and that's tied to your PSN account. I still think it's a pretty good deal, you purchase a game for $60 and get a PSN voucher worth $30-40 with it. If you wish for a physical copy, you can always sell the voucher on eBay and get a physical copy...